# Clean way to allow django users to login the admin and create new users?

Tags: django, django-admin, admin

What is the cleanest way to allow a user to enter `admin` site,

`settings is_staff = true`

and only allowing them to create and edit new users?
I do not want them to be doing or able to be doing anything on admin.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You could give them the is_staff attribute, put them in a custom group you make, and give that group permissions only for adding and editing users. That's straightforward and easy to do. Be cautious, though--sometimes add on products use `is_staff` as a permission check for "can do slightly dangerous thing". You might need to audit carefully to make sure these "pseduo-staff" users aren't getting too many permissions in 3rd party products. You should also be aware that they could make other `is_staff` or `is_superuser` users, allowing them to escape this security box. (You can choose to not show these fields via choices in your admin.py, but you might find it inconvenient that the true admins wouldn't have access to them then)

or, much better:

- You can make a custom forms for user creation and editing, subclassing the existing user creation and editing forms. Then you'd have control over exactly what fields can appear. This is a much better solution.

Comment: I liked the second solution.